How to Access Expo Dashboard Secrets in EAS Update for Sentry Integration in React Native?
I have a React Native application created with Expo and use Expo EAS Build for my preview and production builds.
I have three environment variables:

EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL: This changes based on whether the build is for preview or production.
Two secret keys, one of which is SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN.

Locally, I use a .env file for environment variables when working in development, but I don't include SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN there because Sentry isn't needed in development.
For EAS Build, I have added EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL to eas.json as follows:
{
  "preview": {
    "channel": "preview",
    "distribution": "internal",
    "env": {
      "APP_VARIANT": "preview",
      "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://my-staging-url.com"
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "channel": "production",
    "autoIncrement": true,
    "env": {
      "APP_VARIANT": "production",
      "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://my-prod-url.com"
    }
  }
}

The other two environment variables have been added as secrets in the Expo dashboard. So far, everything works perfectly.
I'm now setting up Expo EAS Update based on the documentation:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/#app-configuration
When I run the command eas update --branch preview, I noticed that EAS Update takes the environment variables from my local .env file. However, it doesn't have access to the secrets from the Expo dashboard.
As a result, when I make an update, the app doesn't report errors to Sentry because SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN is undefined. I also run the command npx sentry-expo-upload-sourcemaps dist but get the same result.
How can I ensure that EAS Update has access to the secrets from the Expo dashboard, specifically for SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN, to properly report errors to Sentry?
I understand that Expo environment variables need to start with EXPO_PUBLIC_ to be recognised, so that's why I can't add it to my local .env file as I do with the other two.
Any ideas or suggestions?

The Secrets set in Expo Dashboard are only available in the EAS Builds. They are not pulled from EAS to your local environment.
If you create an EAS Update without the SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN your application will report all errors, but because of the missing token source maps won't be uploaded for the update so you will see a stack trace pointing to the bundle instead of the original source code.
To upload the source maps using npx sentry-expo-upload-sourcemaps dist you need SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN in your local environment. You can create the token like follows:

Go to sentry.io
Open Settings -> Developer Settings -> Auth Tokens
Click Create New Token

More at https://docs.sentry.io/account/auth-tokens/
Disclaimer: I work at Sentry.

thanks a lot for your time and your answer. Probably I'm missing something, but I have tried reporting an error after an EAS Update (by throwing an error when pressing a button) and this error is not tracked in Sentry. The same error is correctly tracked when I build my app with EAS Build, so it seems like my app looses the Sentry connection after an EAS Update.

Thank you for the follow-up, it seems like the issue is unrelated to the Sentry Auth Token.
Can you open a new issue at https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues with an example of how are you testing the EAS Updates?

Thank you Krystof, I've opened an issue as you suggested: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/4002
